# How to pass parameters to an angular js function using brackets.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to do something like this:

```
<a ng-click="doSomething({{value}})" >
```

js

```
$scope.doSomething = function(a){
 console.log(a);
}
```

Comment: If value is defined on the controller's scope, just use `"doSomething(value)"`.

Comment: According to the [AngularJS documentation on ngClick](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) you don't need curley braces for your variables.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

all you need to do is this:

```
<a ng-click="doSomething(value)" >
```

Comment: Assuming we are using ng-repeat="stuff in bunchOfStuff"
is something like <a ng-click="doSomething(stuff.value)"> legal?

Comment: Yes it is legal.